# Show Exception message when passing invalid argument type

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have a function

```
<?php
public function setStatusToReadyToShip(array $order_item_ids, $delivery_type, $shipping_provider = '', $tracking_number = '')
{
  //code
}
```

Now I want the caller to call this method by providing $order_item_ids in array format.

One way i could do is to check `is_array($order_item_ids)` and send the error to the caller. But i am to utilize Type Hinting. How would i send the user the error response when using type hinting. As currently it crashes the application and says

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Class::SetStatusToReadyToShip() must be of the type array, integer given
```

I am not familiar with the try catch stuff that much. I tried placing try-catch inside this function so that it does not crash the application but the same output received.

Thanks

Comment: Look at your exception message, where the exception is thrown on which line and catch it there.

Comment: It is in the first line inside `setStatusToReadyToShip` method.

Comment: *try* to put your try-catch block around your function call.

Comment: This is the opposite solution of what i am asking. I don't want my api users to put try and catch. Instead i want to handle it inside the class

Answer (score 2):

It is **Catchable fatal error** with constant [E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR](http://set_error_handler)

There are 2 methods to solve this problem (at least two).

1. Create your own exception handler and [set it](http://set_error_handler) as main error handler.
2. Make type validation in your function, and throw exception from it:

   ```
   function setStatusToReadyToShip($order_item_ids, $delivery_type, $shipping_provider = '', $tracking_number = '')
   {
     if (!is_array($order_item_ids)) {
         throw new InvalidArgumentException('First parameter of function '.__FUNCTION__.' must be array');
     }
     // your code
   }
   ```

   and than catch it

   ```
   try {
       setStatusToReadyToShip(5, 6);
   } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
       var_dump($e->getMessage());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class YourClass {
    public static function _init() {
        set_error_handler('YourClass::_typeHintHandler');
    }

    public static function _typeHintHandler($errorCode, $errorMessage) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($errorMessage);  
    }

    public function setStatusToReadyToShip(array $order_item_ids, $delivery_type, $shipping_provider = '', $tracking_number = '')
    {

    }
}
YourClass::_init();

$yo = new YourClass();
try {
    $yo->setStatusToReadyToShip("test");
}catch(Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```